# Metadata rejected- replied but no response 2 days after?

Tags: app-store-connect

My app status changed to Metadata Rejected because they needed to ask me something. I answered 2 days ago and haven't gotten a reply nor has it changed back to in review. Is this normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is normal? I am a developer and although Apple is extremely helpful, they don't have standards when it comes to deadlines. You are at the mercy of their prioritizing. It can take anywhere form 1-7 *business* days for metadata rejected apps. Fix the metadata they are referencing and submit back to them like you have done. There is no set time they guarantee to respond to you, but they will definetly respond. They won't leave you hanging.

Comment: @user3042719 again, 1-7 is a general consensus for metadata apps, but that's not a concrete number. It can take longer (holidays etc etc) the good thing about a meta rejected app is you don't have to submit a new binary and it is usually re-reviewed more promptly as opposed to an internal coding rejection

Comment: Additionally @user3042719 if you don't correct the deficiencies they referenced they won't re-review it. But you stated they had to ask you a question, in that case you will just have to stand by for the reply